# Angular.js recursive json display with dynamic reload

Tags: angularjs, recursion, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following setup:

Jetty-Server with rest API, currently dumb, just taking json per PUT and delivering the same per GET

Web UI with angular: It calls the server once every 2 seconds to get potentially changed data (working) and write it into my var `devices`.
I display the data with a recursive template and `ng-repeat` just like the json hierarchy happens, with input fields for the leaf-values (tree-like look at json).

*My problem:* I want to change the view's values when new data arrives.
Currently it renders once and does not notice the background data being changed.
The data is displayed by `ng-model="value"` on input, because the template gets it by `ng-repeat="(key, value) in value"`
I need something like generating an additional array as model to receive changes by `device` updates.

*Next step problem:* When I manually change values at the view's input fields, i want to collect the (by me) changed data to later press apply and PUT it on to the server. There must be a difference between:

- update from server -> update view (except manually edited and unsubmitted data)

and

- collect manually edited data as tree (like a path to changed value)

The device's data looks like this:

```
{
    "inverter1":{
        "properties":{
            "max_pac":{
                "value":"6400"
            },
            "type_abbreviation":{
                "value":"6400u"
            },
            "serial_number":{
                "value":"1234"
            }
        }
    },
    "inverter2":{
        "properties":{
            "max_pac":{
                "value":"1000"
            },
            "type_abbreviation":{
                "value":"tl3.20"
            },
            "serial_number":{
                "value":"tl3.1243.3456"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My ng-template and where it's called (cleaned up to the most necessary):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="value.html">
   <!-- see below -->
</div>
```

I got all this logic in my head and already rewrote my code about four times the past three days, but now I need your help. I tried to get the snippet to work with JSFiddle, but it didn't work. Don't know why.
Some words pointing in the right direction could be helpful! 
Thanks!

[EDIT]: Good morning again, the follwoing fiddle is a full copy&paste of my code, I deleted the snippet from above.
For better understanding: The server json data change can create new fields in json or might add a new inverter device! So basically everything needs to be updated.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/01ybyxaL/1/)

Comment: could you post the code which maintains the view model i.e. loads the JSON into 'devices'

Comment: Hey, I will - on monday. SO was my last chance but the files are at work, sorry!

I made a $http.get() and on finish it's like $scope.devices = data;
A bit of switching loading indicators on an off but nothing more.